# Looking for high performance Java xy line plotter/grapher

Tags: java, charts, signal-processing, graphing

Hi I am looking to use Java to display EMG (Electromyography) signals. I have tried JChart2D but it is not fast enough for a duo core 2.4Ghz machine. I am trying to view up to 32 channels at 1 KHz and would like to have about 5 seconds worth of data view-able for each channel. A refresh rate of about 20Hz is good enough (every 50ms).

Has anyone done anything similar in Java? If so can you refer me to the library you used?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the charts in JavaFX 2 ? I've not used them for real time updates yet but JavaFX in itself seems plenty fast.
Intro to the charts API
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm

Comment: Have a look at the JavaFX [Ensemble sample application](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.0.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Charts/Area/Adv%20Area%20Audio%20Chart) for some sample charts.  This might give you a reasonable idea of whether JavaFX would be a good fit for your application.